Не устанавливается драйвер Nvidia
Возникли проблемы при установке драйвера на видеокарту Nvidia. Используется debian 12 с оболочкой Gnome на ноутбуке.
Процессор: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10500H CPU @ 2.50GHz со встроенной графикой
и видеокарта:GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q
Перед установкой драйвера накатил ядро 6.10.11-x64v3-xanmod1
Использовал nvidia-detect
Получил:

Detected NVIDIA GPUs:
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] [10de:2520] (rev a1)
Checking card:  NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
Your card is supported by all driver versions.
Your card is also supported by the Tesla 470 drivers series.
It is recommended to install the
nvidia-driver
package.

Начал установку:
sudo apt install nvidia-driver

Вывод:

Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей… Готово
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Уже установлен пакет nvidia-driver самой новой версии (535.183.01-1~deb12u1).
Следующие пакеты устанавливались автоматически и больше не требуются:
brasero-common cdrdao folks-common gir1.2-clutter-1.0 gir1.2-cogl-1.0 gir1.2-coglpango-1.0 gir1.2-geocodeglib-2.0 gir1.2-grilo-0.3 gir1.2-gst-plugins-bad-1.0 gir1.2-gtkclutter-1.0 gir1.2-mediaart-2.0
gir1.2-rest-1.0 gir1.2-shumate-1.0 gir1.2-tracker-3.0 libbrasero-media3-1 libburn4 libevent-2.1-7 libfolks-eds26 libfolks26 libgpod-common libgpod4 libisofs6 libjte2 liblirc-client0 libminiupnpc17 libnatpmp1
libperl4-corelibs-perl libraw20 libsgutils2-1.46-2 libshumate-1.0-1 libshumate-common media-player-info python3-mako python3-markupsafe
Для их удаления используйте «sudo apt autoremove».
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 0 пакетов не обновлено.
Установлено или удалено не до конца 2 пакетов.
После данной операции объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 0 B.
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н]

Вывод после подтверждения:

Настраивается пакет nvidia-kernel-dkms (535.183.01-1~deb12u1) …
Removing old nvidia-current-535.183.01 DKMS files... Deleting module
nvidia-current-535.183.01 completely from the DKMS tree. Loading new
nvidia-current-535.183.01 DKMS files... Building for
6.10.11-x64v3-xanmod1 Building initial module for 6.10.11-x64v3-xanmod1 Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.10.11-x64v3-xanmod1 (x86_64) Consult
/var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/535.183.01/build/make.log for more
information. dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета nvidia-kernel-dkms
(--configure):  подпроцесс из пакета nvidia-kernel-dkms установлен
сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 10 dpkg: зависимости
пакетов не позволяют настроить пакет nvidia-driver:  nvidia-driver
зависит от nvidia-kernel-dkms (= 535.183.01-1~deb12u1) |
nvidia-kernel-535.183.01 | nvidia-open-kernel-535.183.01, однако:
Пакет nvidia-kernel-dkms пока не настроен.   Пакет
nvidia-kernel-535.183.01 не установлен.   Пакет nvidia-kernel-dkms,
предоставляющий nvidia-kernel-535.183.01, пока не настроен.   Пакет
nvidia-open-kernel-535.183.01 не установлен. dpkg: ошибка при
обработке пакета nvidia-driver (--configure):  проблемы зависимостей —
оставляем не настроенным При обработке следующих пакетов произошли
ошибки:  nvidia-kernel-dkms  nvidia-driver E: Sub-process
/usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

После перезагрузки начало выдавать ошибки на загрузке:
sudo journalctl -b -u systemd-modules-load.service


сен 30 17:05:59 Tetris systemd-modules-load[344]: Inserted module 'lp'
сен 30 17:05:59 Tetris systemd-modules-load[344]: Inserted module
'ppdev'
сен 30 17:05:59 Tetris systemd-modules-load[344]: Inserted module
'parport_pc'
сен 30 17:05:59 Tetris systemd-modules-load[344]: Inserted module
'msr'
сен 30 17:05:59 Tetris systemd-modules-load[359]: modprobe: FATAL:
Module nvidia-current not found in directory
/lib/modules/6.10.11-x64v3-xanmod1
сен 30 17:05:59 Tetris systemd-modules-load[357]: modprobe: ERROR:
../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1047 command_do() Error running install
command 'modprobe -i nvidia-current ' for module nvidia: retcode 1
сен 30 17:05:59 Tetris systemd-modules-load[357]: modprobe: ERROR:
could not insert 'nvidia': Invalid argument
сен 30 17:05:59 Tetris systemd-modules-load[360]: modprobe: FATAL:
Module nvidia-current-modeset not found in directory
/lib/modules/6.10.11-x64v3-xanmod1
сен 30 17:05:59 Tetris systemd-modules-load[355]: modprobe: ERROR:
../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1047 command_do() Error running install
command 'modprobe nvidia ; modprobe -i nvidia-current-modeset ' for
module>
сен 30 17:05:59 Tetris systemd-modules-load[355]: modprobe: ERROR:
could not insert 'nvidia_modeset': Invalid argument
сен 30 17:05:59 Tetris systemd-modules-load[361]: modprobe: FATAL:
Module nvidia-current-drm not found in directory
/lib/modules/6.10.11-x64v3-xanmod1
сен 30 17:05:59 Tetris systemd-modules-load[344]: Error running
install command 'modprobe nvidia-modeset ; modprobe -i
nvidia-current-drm ' for module nvidia_drm: retcode 1
сен 30 17:05:59 Tetris systemd-modules-load[344]: Failed to insert
module 'nvidia_drm': Invalid argument
сен 30 17:05:59 Tetris systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main
process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
сен 30 17:05:59 Tetris systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service:
Failed with result 'exit-code'.
сен 30 17:05:59 Tetris systemd[1]: Failed to start
systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules.
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd[1]: Starting
systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules...
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[550]: modprobe: FATAL:
Module nvidia-current not found in directory
/lib/modules/6.10.11-x64v3-xanmod1
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[548]: modprobe: ERROR:
../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1047 command_do() Error running install
command 'modprobe -i nvidia-current ' for module nvidia: retcode 1
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[548]: modprobe: ERROR:
could not insert 'nvidia': Invalid argument
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[551]: modprobe: FATAL:
Module nvidia-current-modeset not found in directory
/lib/modules/6.10.11-x64v3-xanmod1
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[545]: modprobe: ERROR:
../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1047 command_do() Error running install
command 'modprobe nvidia ; modprobe -i nvidia-current-modeset ' for
module>
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[545]: modprobe: ERROR:
could not insert 'nvidia_modeset': Invalid argument
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[552]: modprobe: FATAL:
Module nvidia-current-drm not found in directory
/lib/modules/6.10.11-x64v3-xanmod1
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[542]: Error running
install command 'modprobe nvidia-modeset ; modprobe -i
nvidia-current-drm ' for module nvidia_drm: retcode 1
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[542]: Failed to insert
module 'nvidia_drm': Invalid argument
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main
process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service:
Failed with result 'exit-code'.
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd[1]: Failed to start
systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules.
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd[1]: Starting
systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules...
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[562]: modprobe: FATAL:
Module nvidia-current not found in directory
/lib/modules/6.10.11-x64v3-xanmod1
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[560]: modprobe: ERROR:
../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1047 command_do() Error running install
command 'modprobe -i nvidia-current ' for module nvidia: retcode 1
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[560]: modprobe: ERROR:
could not insert 'nvidia': Invalid argument
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[563]: modprobe: FATAL:
Module nvidia-current-modeset not found in directory
/lib/modules/6.10.11-x64v3-xanmod1
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[558]: modprobe: ERROR:
../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1047 command_do() Error running install
command 'modprobe nvidia ; modprobe -i nvidia-current-modeset ' for
module>
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[558]: modprobe: ERROR:
could not insert 'nvidia_modeset': Invalid argument
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[564]: modprobe: FATAL:
Module nvidia-current-drm not found in directory
/lib/modules/6.10.11-x64v3-xanmod1
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[556]: Error running
install command 'modprobe nvidia-modeset ; modprobe -i
nvidia-current-drm ' for module nvidia_drm: retcode 1
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[556]: Failed to insert
module 'nvidia_drm': Invalid argument
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: Main
process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service:
Failed with result 'exit-code'.
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd[1]: Failed to start
systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules.
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd[1]: Starting
systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules...
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[592]: modprobe: FATAL:
Module nvidia-current not found in directory
/lib/modules/6.10.11-x64v3-xanmod1
сен 30 17:06:00 Tetris systemd-modules-load[590]: modprobe: ERROR:
../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1047 command_do() Error running install
command 'modprobe -i nvidia-current ' for module nvidia: retcode 1

UPD:Возможна ошибка в том, что версии gcc отличается:

warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
The kernel was built by: gcc-14 (Debian 14.2.0-3) 14.2.0   You are
using:           gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0

Но не знаю в правильной ли я стороне двигаюсь и что с этим делать.

«Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-current/535.183.01/build/make.log for more information.»

@andreymal Maybe that's the problem?
The kernel was built by: gcc-14 (Debian 14.2.0-3) 14.2.0
You are using:           gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0
